# How do I break my code into subroutines - Java

Tags: java, subroutine

I have written a code for data management and parallel arrays but it has to be broken into methods/subroutines. Whenever I try to do so, some aspect of my code stops working. Would it be possible for anyone to roughly outline how and what I can break into subroutines without it causing problems in my code? I know this is a very specific question and the site discourages this but I really have no clue how to decide which parts of your code go into subroutines as a general rule.

```
    Scanner keyedInput = new Scanner(System.in); // input

    // variables
    String userInput;
    int numberOfBooks = 0; // setting to 0
    int userChoice = 0; // setting to 0
    final double taxAmount = 1.13;
    boolean valid = false;
    double total = 0;
    double taxedTotal;

    // while loop for number of books
    while (valid == false)
    {
        // user enters info
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of books you have purchased: ");
        userInput = keyedInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println();

        // try catch statements for invalid input/exceptions
        try
        {
            numberOfBooks = Integer.parseInt(userInput); // converting to int
            valid = true; // setting to true so loop won't repeat
        } // end of try

        // outputting invalid input message
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Your input is not valid");
            System.out.println();
        } // end of catch
    } // end of valid == false while loop


    // arrays to hold info user will input
    String bookName [ ] = new String [numberOfBooks];
    double price [ ] = new double [numberOfBooks];

    // user enters all data required
    System.out.println("* * * * DATA ENTRY * * * *");

    // for loop that prompts for and stores name of books purchases
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBooks; i = i + 1)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of book " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        bookName[i] = keyedInput.nextLine(); // stores the name of each book in the array

        // set valid to false again for loop below
        valid = false;

        // while loop for price of books
        while (valid == false)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Please enter the price of '" + (bookName[i] + "': "));
            userInput = keyedInput.nextLine();


            // try catch statements for invalid input/exceptions
            try 
            {
                price[i] = Double.parseDouble(userInput); // converting to double
                valid = true; // setting to true so loop won't repeat
            } // end of try

            // outputting invalid input message
            catch (NumberFormatException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Your input is not valid");
            } // end of catch
        } // end of valid == false while loop
    } // end of for loop


        // while loop to output data
        while (userChoice != 3)
        {
            // set valid to false for loop below
            valid = false; 

            while (valid == false)
            {
                // outputting choices menu
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("* * * *\n" + "1. Output original data \n" + "2. Output calculated data \n" + "3. Exit \n" + "* * * *\n");

                // user enters their choice
                System.out.print("Please enter the number in front of your choice: ");
                userInput = keyedInput.nextLine();
                System.out.println();

                // try catch statements for invalid input/exceptions
                try 
                {
                    userChoice = Integer.parseInt(userInput); // converting to int
                    valid = true; // setting to true so loop won't repeat
                } // end of try

                // outputting invalid input message
                catch (NumberFormatException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Your input is not valid");
                    System.out.println();
                } // end of catch
            } // end of valid == false while loop


            // switch statements for each option
            switch (userChoice)
            {
                // option 1
                case 1:
                {
                    // for loop to output existing data
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBooks; i = i + 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("'" + bookName[i] + "'" + " cost: " + price[i]);
                    } // end of for loop
                    break;
                } // end of case 1

                // option 2
                case 2: 
                {
                    // calculations for total + taxed total
                    for (double value : price) 
                    {
                        total = total + value;
                        total = Math.round(total * 100.0) / 100.0; // rounding
                    } // end of for loop    

                    taxedTotal = (total * taxAmount); // calculating total with taxes
                    taxedTotal = Math.round(taxedTotal * 100.0) / 100.0; // rounding

                    System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
                    System.out.println("Taxed total: $" + taxedTotal);
                    break;
                } // end of case 2

                // option 3
                case 3:
                {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                } // end of case 3
            } // end of switch statements
        } // end of userChoice while loop
```

Comment: This question is better suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: In Java, subroutines are called methods.  A method can return one value.  That value can be a class instance that holds more than one related value.  Any group of code that creates or returns one value is a candidate to be put in a method.

Answer (score 0):

A method does stuff. A good method does one thing and does it well. It may use other methods to get the job done. Break your task down into the jobs that need to be done, then write the methods that do those jobs. Easy.

Your task is to build and manage a library:

```
1) build a library
2) print the library 
3) print the value of the library
99) other stuff
```

What is a library? It is a collection of books. What is a book? It is a thing with a title and cost and maybe other attributes that we can print.

```
class Book {
    String title;
    float cost;
    // create a new book
    public Book (String name, float price) {
       title = name;
       cost = price;
    }
    // 
    public String toString() {
       return "'" + title + "'" + " cost: " + cost;
    }
}
```

A library is a collection of books.

```
ArrayList <Book> library = new ArrayList<>();
```

We need to ask the user for information. Sometimes we want strings, sometimes numbers:

```
String getUserString(String prompt) {        
    System.out.print("\n"+prompt);
    return keyedInput.nextLine();
}

float getUserFloat(String prompt);
    boolean valid = false;
    // do stuff to get a float
    return number;
}

int getUserInt(String prompt);
    boolean valid = false;
    // do stuff to get an int
    return number;
}
```

Now we can build a library by calling the methods we have built:

```
int numberOfBooks = getUserInt("Please enter the number of books you have purchased: ");
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfBooks; i++){ 
    String title = getUserString("Please enter the name of book " + i + ": ");
    float cost = getUserFloat("Please enter the price of '" + title + "': "));
    library.append(new Book(title, cost));
}
```

I leave the rest to you with one hint...

```
for (Book book : library) {
    System.out.println(book.toString());
}
```